# Updating Swing DefaultComboBoxModel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

I´m trying to update a DefaultComboBoxModel named 'mdlCategory' with that piece of code.

```
private void categoriesUpdate(String categoryName, boolean addElement) {

    if (!categoryName.equals("")) {

        if (addElement) {//that block works propertly
            Category c = new Category(-1);
            c.setName(categoryName);
            mdlCategory.addElement(c);
            selAllergenCategory.setSelectedItem(c);
        } else {//not works!!
            Category cat = (Category) mdlCategories.getSelectedItem();
            cat.setName(categoryName);
            selAllergenCategory.setSelectedItem(cat);
        }
    }
}
```

When addElement is true, a new category is added to the model in a correct way.

I have the problem in 'else' block...when try to update a category getting it from DefaultComboBoxModel the model doesn't change in a proper way, even removing and adding it again, although when I pass the cursor over the combo, the change happens but not persist.

Am I updating the model's category object in a wrong way?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` with one `JComboBox` and `JButton` invoked a.m. issues, otherwise no idea

Answer (score 0):

You should inform Swing about changes in your model. In if-block it makes mdlCategory.addElement(c);
. For else-block you should call setElementAt:

```
} else {//not works!!
            Category cat = (Category) mdlCategories.getSelectedItem();
            int idx = mdlCategories.indexOf(cat);
            cat.setName(categoryName);
            mdlCategory.setElementAt(cat, idx);
            selAllergenCategory.setSelectedItem(cat);
}
```

Probably last line (selAllergenCategory.setSelectedItem(cat);) is not required